# docker based build with visual studio - doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio, docker

I wish to do **docker-based builds** using different versions of **visual studio**.

I followed the instructions on

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/build-tools-container?view=vs-2019

and these don't work.

In particular, the failure appears to be with line:

> Step 4/5 : RUN C:\TEMP\vs_buildtools.exe --quiet --wait --norestart
>   --nocache     --installPath C:\BuildTools     --all     --remove Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.10240     --remove
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.10586     --remove
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.14393     --remove
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows81SDK  || IF
>   "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="3010" EXIT 0

of the docker file. This produces no error message, but takes no time, and performs no install.

So obviously subsequent steps dont work either. I've tried fiddling with the options but to no avail.

I tried to get support from MSFT via the link suggested in the above guide (https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/support/#talktous) and that has also been fruitless.

Has anyone gotten anything like this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured this out (with some help from MSFT).

It appears the tool to download and install visual studio doesn't do an awesome job reporting out of disk space errors (like hitchhikers guide, it reports down in the basement, behind a closet).

And the function to allow you to extend your disk space in a container is currently broken (with docker / windows).

But by restricting what I installed, I got under the limit, and produced a working container.

Here is an example of a working docker file:

https://github.com/SophistSolutions/Stroika/blob/922b282c09fc57d76a7ba7d4d8a5c031b63655dd/DockerBuildContainers/Windows-Cygwin-VS2k19/Dockerfile

You have to build the container in windows, and then run the container in windows (host os).